# Without root access, run R with tuned BLAS when it is linked with reference BLAS

Tags: r, linux, shared-libraries, ld, blas

Can any one tell me why I can **not successfully** test OpenBLAS's `dgemm` performance (in GFLOPs) in R via the following way?

1. link R with the "reference BLAS" `libblas.so`
2. compile my C program `mmperf.c` with OpenBLAS library `libopenblas.so`
3. load the resulting shared library `mmperf.so` into R, call the R wrapper function `mmperf` and report `dgemm` performance in GFLOPs.

Point 1 looks strange, but I have no choice because I have no root access on machines I want to test, so actual linking to OpenBLAS is impossible. By **"not successfully"** I mean my program ends up reporting `dgemm` performance for reference BLAS instead of OpenBLAS. I hope someone can explain to me:

1. why my way does not work;
2. is it possible at all to make it work (this is important, because if it is impossible, I must write a C `main` function and do my job in a C program.)

I've investigated into this issue for two days, here I will include various system output to assist you to make a diagnose. To make things reproducible, I will also include the code, makefile as well as shell command.

**Part 1: system environment before testing**

There are 2 ways to invoke R, either using `R` or `Rscript`. There are some differences in what is loaded when they are invoked:

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ readelf -d $(R RHOME)/bin/exec/R | grep "NEEDED"
0x00000001 (NEEDED)         Shared library: [libR.so]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)         Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)         Shared library: [libc.so.6]

~/Desktop/dgemm$ readelf -d $(R RHOME)/bin/Rscript | grep "NEEDED"
0x00000001 (NEEDED)         Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Here we need to choose `Rscript`, because `R` loads `libR.so`, which will automatically load the reference BLAS `libblas.so.3`:

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ readelf -d $(R RHOME)/lib/libR.so | grep blas
0x00000001 (NEEDED)         Shared library: [libblas.so.3]

~/Desktop/dgemm$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3
... 31 May /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3 -> /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.0

~/Desktop/dgemm$ readelf -d /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3 | grep SONAME
0x0000000e (SONAME)         Library soname: [libblas.so.3]
```

Comparatively, `Rscript` gives a cleaner environment.

**Part 2: OpenBLAS**

After downloading source file from [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/) and a simple `make` command, a shared library of the form `libopenblas-<arch>-<release>.so-<version>` can be generated. Note that we will not have root access to install it; instead, we copy this library into our working directory `~/Desktop/dgemm` and rename it simply to `libopenblas.so`. At the same time we have to make another copy with name `libopenblas.so.0`, as this is the *SONAME* which run time loader will seek for:

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ readelf -d libopenblas.so | grep "RPATH\|SONAME"
0x0000000e (SONAME)         Library soname: [libopenblas.so.0]
```

Note that the `RPATH` attribute is not given, which means this library is intended to be put in `/usr/lib` and we should call `ldconfig` to add it to `ld.so.cache`. But again we don't have root access to do this. In fact, if this can be done, then all the difficulties are gone. We could then use `update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3` to effectively link R to OpenBLAS.

**Part 3: C code, Makefile, and R code**

Here is a C script `mmperf.c` computing GFLOPs of multiplying 2 square matrices of size `N`:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <R_ext/BLAS.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

/* standard C subroutine */
double mmperf (int n) {
  /* local vars */
  int n2 = n * n, tmp; double *A, *C, one = 1.0;
  struct timeval t1, t2; double elapsedTime, GFLOPs;
  /* simulate N-by-N matrix A */
  A = (double *)calloc(n2, sizeof(double));
  GetRNGstate();
  tmp = 0; while (tmp < n2) {A[tmp] = runif(0.0, 1.0); tmp++;}
  PutRNGstate();
  /* generate N-by-N zero matrix C */
  C = (double *)calloc(n2, sizeof(double));
  /* time 'dgemm.f' for C <- A * A + C */
  gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
  F77_CALL(dgemm) ("N", "N", &n, &n, &n, &one, A, &n, A, &n, &one, C, &n);
  gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
  /* free memory */
  free(A); free(C);
  /* compute and return elapsedTime in microseconds (usec or 1e-6 sec) */
  elapsedTime = (double)(t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1e+6;
  elapsedTime += (double)(t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec);
  /* convert microseconds to nanoseconds (1e-9 sec) */
  elapsedTime *= 1e+3;
  /* compute and return GFLOPs */
  GFLOPs = 2.0 * (double)n2 * (double)n / elapsedTime;
  return GFLOPs;
  }

/* R wrapper */
SEXP R_mmperf (SEXP n) {
  double GFLOPs = mmperf(asInteger(n));
  return ScalarReal(GFLOPs);
  }
```

Here is a simple R script `mmperf.R` to report GFLOPs for case `N = 2000`

```
mmperf <- function (n) {
  dyn.load("mmperf.so")
  GFLOPs <- .Call("R_mmperf", n)
  dyn.unload("mmperf.so")
  return(GFLOPs)
  }

GFLOPs <- round(mmperf(2000), 2)
cat(paste("GFLOPs =",GFLOPs, "\n"))
```

Finally there is a simple makefile to generate the shared library `mmperf.so`:

```
mmperf.so: mmperf.o
    gcc -shared -L$(shell pwd) -Wl,-rpath=$(shell pwd) -o mmperf.so mmperf.o -lopenblas

mmperf.o: mmperf.c
    gcc -fpic -O2 -I$(shell Rscript --default-packages=base --vanilla -e 'cat(R.home("include"))') -c mmperf.c
```

Put all these files under working directory `~/Desktop/dgemm`, and compile it:

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ make
~/Desktop/dgemm$ readelf -d mmperf.so | grep "NEEDED\|RPATH\|SONAME"
0x00000001 (NEEDED)            Shared library: [libopenblas.so.0]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)            Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x0000000f (RPATH)             Library rpath: [/home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm]
```

The output reassures us that OpenBLAS is correctly linked, and the run time load path is correctly set.

**Part 4: testing OpenBLAS in R**

Let's do

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ Rscript --default-packages=base --vanilla mmperf.R
```

Note our script needs only the `base` package in R, and `--vanilla` is used to ignore all user settings on R start-up. On my laptop, my program returns:

```
GFLOPs = 1.11
```

Oops! This is truely reference BLAS performance not OpenBLAS (which is about 8-9 GFLOPs).

**Part 5: Why?**

To be honest, I don't know why this happens. Each step seems to work correctly. Does something subtle occurs when R is invoked? For example, any possibility that OpenBLAS library is overridden by reference BLAS at some point for some reason? Any explanations and solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to have `.` first in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why my way does not work

First, shared libraries on UNIX are designed to mimic the way archive libraries work (archive libraries were there first). In particular that means that if you have `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so`, both defining symbol `foo`, then whichever library is loaded first is the one that wins: all references to `foo` from anywhere within the program (including from `libbar.so`) will bind to `libfoo.so`s definition of `foo`.

This mimics what would happen if you linked your program against `libfoo.a` and `libbar.a`, where both archive libraries defined the same symbol `foo`. More info on archive linking [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking).

It should be clear from above, that if `libblas.so.3` and `libopenblas.so.0` define the same set of symbols (which they *do*), and if `libblas.so.3` is loaded into the process first, then routines from `libopenblas.so.0` will *never* be called.

Second, you've correctly decided that since `R` directly links against `libR.so`, and since `libR.so` directly links against `libblas.so.3`, it is guaranteed that `libopenblas.so.0` will lose the battle.

However, you *erroneously* decided that `Rscript` is better, but it's not: `Rscript` is a *tiny* binary (11K on my system; compare to 2.4MB for `libR.so`), and approximately all it does is `exec` of `R`. This is trivial to see in `strace` output:

```
strace -e trace=execve /usr/bin/Rscript --default-packages=base --vanilla /dev/null
execve("/usr/bin/Rscript", ["/usr/bin/Rscript", "--default-packages=base", "--vanilla", "/dev/null"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
execve("/usr/lib/R/bin/R", ["/usr/lib/R/bin/R", "--slave", "--no-restore", "--vanilla", "--file=/dev/null", "--args"], [/* 43 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=89625, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=89626, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
execve("/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R", ["/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R", "--slave", "--no-restore", "--vanilla", "--file=/dev/null", "--args"], [/* 51 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=89630, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Which means that by the time your script starts executing, `libblas.so.3` has been loaded, and `libopenblas.so.0` that will be loaded as a dependency of `mmperf.so` will not *actually* be used for anything.

> is it possible at all to make it work

Probably. I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Pretend that `libopenblas.so.0` is actually `libblas.so.3`
2. Rebuild entire `R` package against `libopenblas.so`.

For #1, you need to `ln -s libopenblas.so.0 libblas.so.3`, *then* make sure that your copy of `libblas.so.3` is found before the system one, by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately.

This appears to work for me:

```
mkdir /tmp/libblas
# pretend that libc.so.6 is really libblas.so.3
cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /tmp/libblas/libblas.so.3
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/libblas /usr/bin/Rscript /dev/null
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3: undefined symbol: cgemv_
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

Note how I got an error (my "pretend" `libblas.so.3` doesn't define symbols expected of it, since it's really a copy of `libc.so.6`).

You can also confirm which version of `libblas.so.3` is getting loaded this way:

```
LD_DEBUG=libs LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/libblas /usr/bin/Rscript /dev/null |& grep 'libblas\.so\.3'
     91533: find library=libblas.so.3 [0]; searching
     91533:   trying file=/usr/lib/R/lib/libblas.so.3
     91533:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3
     91533:   trying file=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libblas.so.3
     91533:   trying file=/tmp/libblas/libblas.so.3
     91533: calling init: /tmp/libblas/libblas.so.3
```

For #2, you said:

> I have no root access on machines I want to test, so actual linking to OpenBLAS is impossible.

but that seems to be a bogus argument: if you can build `libopenblas`, surely you can also build your own version of `R`.

**Update:**

> You mentioned in the beginning that libblas.so.3 and libopenblas.so.0 define the same symbol, what does this mean? They have different SONAME, is that insufficient to distinguish them by the system?

The symbols and the `SONAME` have *nothing* to do with each other.

You can see symbols in the output from `readelf -Ws libblas.so.3` and `readelf -Ws libopenblas.so.0`. Symbols related to `BLAS`, such as `cgemv_`, will appear in both libraries.

Your confusion about `SONAME` *possibly* comes from Windows. The `DLL`s on Windows are designed completely differently. In particular, when `FOO.DLL` imports symbol `bar` from `BAR.DLL`, *both* the name of the symbol (`bar`) *and* the `DLL` from which that symbol was imported (`BAR.DLL`) are recorded in the `FOO.DLL`s import table.

That makes it easy to have `R` import `cgemv_` from `BLAS.DLL`, while `MMPERF.DLL` imports the same symbol from `OPENBLAS.DLL`.

However, that makes [library interpositioning](http://www.drdobbs.com/building-library-interposers-for-fun-and/184404926) hard, and works completely differently from the way archive libraries work (even on Windows).

Opinions differ on which design is better overall, but neither system is likely to ever change its model.

There are ways for UNIX to emulate Windows-style symbol binding: see `RTLD_DEEPBIND` in dlopen [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). Beware: these are fraught with peril, likely to confuse UNIX experts, are not widely used, and likely to have implementation bugs.

**Update 2:**

> you mean I compile R and install it under my home directory?

Yes.

> Then when I want to invoke it, I should explicitly give the path to my version of executable program, otherwise the one on the system might be invoked instead? Or, can I put this path at the first position of environment variable $PATH to cheat the system?

Either way works.

Comment: `UND` is undefined, i.e. imported from some other library.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I suggest you ask a different question, show exact errors you are getting from setting `LD_PRELOAD`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

*********************

## Solution 1:

*********************

Thanks to [Employed Russian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50617/employed-russian), my problem is finally solved. The investigation requires important skills in **Linux system debugging and patching**, and I believe this is a great asset I learned. Here I would post a solution, as well as correcting several points in my original post.

## 1 About invoking R

In my original post, I mentioned there are two ways to launch R, either via `R` or `Rscript`. However, I have wrongly exaggerated their difference. Let's now investigate their start-up process, via an important Linux debugging facility `strace` (see [`man strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)). There are actually lots of interesting things happening after we type a command in the shell, and we can use

```
strace -e trace=process [command]
```

to trace  all  system  calls involving process management. As a result we can watch the fork, wait, and execution steps of a process. Though not stated in the manual page, @Employed Russian shows that it is possible to specify only a subclass of `process`, for example, `execve` for the execution steps.

For `R` we have

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ time strace -e trace=execve R --vanilla < /dev/null > /dev/null
execve("/usr/bin/R", ["R", "--vanilla"], [/* 70 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=5777, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
execve("/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R", ["/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R", "--vanilla"], [/* 79 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=5778, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++

real    0m0.345s
user    0m0.256s
sys     0m0.068s
```

while for `Rscript` we have

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ time strace -e trace=execve Rscript --default-packages=base --vanilla /dev/null
execve("/usr/bin/Rscript", ["Rscript", "--default-packages=base", "--vanilla", "/dev/null"], [/* 70 vars */]) = 0
execve("/usr/lib/R/bin/R", ["/usr/lib/R/bin/R", "--slave", "--no-restore", "--vanilla", "--file=/dev/null"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=5822, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=5823, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
execve("/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R", ["/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R", "--slave", "--no-restore", "--vanilla", "--file=/dev/null"], [/* 80 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=5827, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++

real    0m0.063s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.028s
```

We have also used `time` to measure the start-up time. Note that

1. `Rscript` is about 5.5 times faster than `R`. One reason is that `R` will load 6 default packages on start-up, while `Rscript` only loads one `base` package by control: `--default-packages=base`. But it is still much faster even without this setting.
2. In the end both start-up processes are directed to `$(R RHOME)/bin/exec/R`, and in my original post, I have already exploited `readelf -d` to show that this executable will load `libR.so`, which are linked with `libblas.so.3`. According to @Employed Russian's explanation, the BLAS library loaded first will win, so there is no way my original method will work.
3. To successfully run `strace`, we have used the **amazing** file `/dev/null` as input file and output file when necessary. For example, `Rscript` demands an input file, while `R` demands both. We feed the null device to both to make the command run smoothly and the output clean. The null device is a physically existing file, but works amazingly. When reading from it, it contains nothing; while writing to it, it discards everything.

## 2. Cheat R

Now since `libblas.so` will be loaded anyway, the only thing we can do is to provide our own version of this library. As I have said in the original post, if we have root access, this is really easy, by using `update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3`, so that the system Linux will help us complete this switch. But @Employed Russian offers an awesome way to cheat the system without root access: **let's check how R finds BLAS library on start-up, and make sure we feed our version before the system default is found!** To monitor how shared libraries are found and loaded, use environment variable `LD_DEBUG`.

There are a number of [Linux environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) with prefix `LD_`, as documented in [`man ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html). These variables can be assigned before an executable, so that we can change the running feature of a program. Some useful variables include:

- `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for setting run time library search path;
- `LD_DEBUG` for tracing look-up and loading of shared libraries;
- `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS` for displaying all loaded library by a program (behaves similar to `ldd`);
- `LD_PRELOAD` for forcing injecting a library to a program at the very start, before all other libraries are looked for;
- `LD_PROFILE` and `LD_PROFILE_OUTPUT` for profiling **one** specified shared library. R user who have read section *3.4.1.1 sprof* of [Writing R extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) should recall that this is used for profiling compiled code from within R.

The use of `LD_DEBUG` can be seen by:

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ LD_DEBUG=help cat
Valid options for the LD_DEBUG environment variable are:

  libs        display library search paths
  reloc       display relocation processing
  files       display progress for input file
  symbols     display symbol table processing
  bindings    display information about symbol binding
  versions    display version dependencies
  scopes      display scope information
  all         all previous options combined
  statistics  display relocation statistics
  unused      determined unused DSOs
  help        display this help message and exit

  To direct the debugging output into a file instead of standard output a filename can be specified using the LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT environment variable.
```

Here we are particularly interested in using `LD_DEBUG=libs`. For example,

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ LD_DEBUG=libs Rscript --default-packages=base --vanilla /dev/null |& grep blas
  5974: find library=libblas.so.3 [0]; searching
  5974:   trying file=/usr/lib/R/lib/libblas.so.3
  5974:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/sse2/libblas.so.3
  5974:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libblas.so.3
  5974:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/libblas.so.3
  5974:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libblas.so.3
  5974:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3
  5974:   trying file=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client/libblas.so.3
  5974:   trying file=/usr/lib/libblas.so.3
  5974: calling init: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3
  5974: calling fini: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 [0]
```

shows various attempts that R program tried to locate and load `libblas.so.3`. So if we could provide our own version of `libblas.so.3`, and make sure R finds it first, then the problem is solved.

Let's first make a symbolic link `libblas.so.3` in our working path to the OpenBLAS library `libopenblas.so`, then expand default `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with our working path (and **export** it):

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ ln -sf libopenblas.so libblas.so.3
~/Desktop/dgemm$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $(pwd):$LD_LIBRARY_PATH  ## put our working path at top
```

Now let's check again the library loading process:

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ LD_DEBUG=libs Rscript --default-packages=base --vanilla /dev/null |& grep blas
  6063: find library=libblas.so.3 [0]; searching
  6063:   trying file=/usr/lib/R/lib/libblas.so.3
  6063:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/sse2/libblas.so.3
  6063:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libblas.so.3
  6063:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/libblas.so.3
  6063:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libblas.so.3
  6063:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3
  6063:   trying file=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client/libblas.so.3
  6063:   trying file=/home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libblas.so.3
  6063: calling init: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libblas.so.3
  6063: calling fini: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libblas.so.3 [0]
```

Great! We have successfully cheated R.

## 3. Experiment with OpenBLAS

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ Rscript --default-packages=base --vanilla mmperf.R
GFLOPs = 8.77
```

Now, everything works as expected!

## 4. Unset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (to be safe)

It is a good practice to unset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after use.

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 3):

*********************

## Solution 2:

*********************

Here we offer another solution, by exploiting environment variable `LD_PRELOAD` mentioned in our [*solution 1*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37075682/4891738). The use of `LD_PRELOAD` is more "brutal", as it forces loading a given library into the program before any other program, even before the C library `libc.so`! This is often used for urgent patching in Linux development.

As shown in the part 2 of the [*original post*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37041819/4891738), the shared BLAS library `libopenblas.so` has *SONAME* `libopenblas.so.0`. An *SONAME* is an internal name that dynamic library loader would seek at run time, so we need to make a symbolic link to `libopenblas.so` with this *SONAME*:

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ ln -sf libopenblas.so libopenblas.so.0
```

then we export it:

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ export LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/libopenblas.so.0
```

Note that a **full path** to `libopenblas.so.0` needs be fed to `LD_PRELOAD` for a successful load, even if `libopenblas.so.0` is under `$(pwd)`.

Now we launch `Rscript` and check what happens by `LD_DEBUG`:

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ LD_DEBUG=libs Rscript --default-packages=base --vanilla /dev/null |& grep blas
  4860: calling init: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libopenblas.so
  4860: calling init: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libopenblas.so
  4865: calling init: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libopenblas.so
  4868: calling fini: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libopenblas.so [0]
  4870: calling init: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libopenblas.so
  4869: calling init: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libopenblas.so
  4867: calling fini: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libopenblas.so [0]
  4860: find library=libblas.so.3 [0]; searching
  4860:   trying file=/usr/lib/R/lib/libblas.so.3
  4860:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/sse2/libblas.so.3
  4860:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libblas.so.3
  4860:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/libblas.so.3
  4860:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libblas.so.3
  4860:   trying file=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3
  4860:   trying file=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client/libblas.so.3
  4860:   trying file=/usr/lib/libblas.so.3
  4860: calling init: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3
  4860: calling init: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libopenblas.so
  4874: calling init: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libopenblas.so
  4876: calling init: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libopenblas.so
  4860: calling fini: /home/zheyuan/Desktop/dgemm/libopenblas.so [0]
  4860: calling fini: /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 [0]
```

Comparing with what we saw in [*solution 1*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37075682/4891738) by cheating R with our own version of `libblas.so.3`, we can see that

- `libopenblas.so.0` is loaded first, hence found first by `Rscript`;
- after `libopenblas.so.0` is found, `Rscript` goes on searching and loading `libblas.so.3`. However, this will play no effect by the *"first come, first serve"* rule, explained in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37064043/4891738).

Good, everything works, so we test our `mmperf.c` program:

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ Rscript --default-packages=base --vanilla mmperf.R
GFLOPs = 9.62
```

The outcome 9.62 is bigger than 8.77 we saw in the earlier solution merely by chance. As a test for using OpenBLAS we don't run the experiment many times for preciser result.

Then as usual, we unset environment variable in the end:

```
~/Desktop/dgemm$ unset LD_PRELOAD
```