# Can Protobuf's oneof deserialization functionality be recreated using Cereal?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, cereal

I am able to write code to deserialize a proto message that contains a oneof section without having to know beforehand what the oneof section contains. I can not figure out how to write a similar set of struct definitions that I can deserialize the same way using Cereal.

I was using Protobufs to serialize/deserialize some data, but I ran into [the same problem as piaoxu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051635/several-shared-object-using-same-proto-leading-the-the-error-file-already-exist). So I switched to using Cereal.

I have been able to convert all of the original proto definitions to C++ struct definitions that can be serialized using Cereal, except the proto definitions that use the oneof functionality.

Here is an example set of a proto definitions that I'd like to convert to structs:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package Messages;

message A {}

message B {}

message Message {
    oneof contents {
        A a = 1;
        B b = 2;
    }
}
```

Here is the corresponding C++ code I had written to deserialize and parse a received `Message`. Using the generated protobuf code, I was able to deserialize a `Message` without first knowing if it contains an `A` or a `B`:

```
void ParseData(const string& data) {
{
    auto message = new Messages::Message();
    message->ParseFromString(data);

    switch (message->contents_case()) {
        case Messages::Message::kA:
            std::cout << "I got an A!" << std::endl;
            break;
        case Messages::Message::kB:
            std::cout << "I got a B!" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And here is my attempt at making an equivalent set of struct definitions:

```
struct A {};

struct B {};

template <class Contents>
struct Message {
    enum Type {
        A,
        B,
    };

    Type type;

    Contents contents;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& archive) {
        archive(type, contents);
    }
};
```

And I'm using these structs to serialize and send a message like so:

```
bool SendA() {
    Message<A> message{};
    ostringstream stream;

    message.type = Message::Type::A;
    message.contents = new A{};

    {
        cereal::PortableBinaryOutputArchive archive(stream);
        archive(message);
    }

    return SendData(stream.str());
}
```

This approach works until I try to deserialize a received `Message`. I would like to be able to deserialize a `Message` *without* first knowing if it contains an `A` or a `B`, but AFAIK this is not possible.

Is this indeed not possible using my current approach? And if so, is there another approach that will allow me to deserialize a similar set of structs without first knowing what it contains?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cereal. In case it helps, `oneof` is not encoded in any way on the wire. The wire representation of `Message` as shown in your example is equivalent to `message Message {A a = 1; B b = 2;}`, with the gentlemen's agreement that only one of `a` and `b` is ever present. Recall that any field in a proto message, unless explicitly marked `required`, may be omitted.

Comment: Thank you Igor! That did help a lot. Once I have 15 rep points and I'm able to I'll give your comment an upvote 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Igor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56924828/can-protobufs-oneof-deserialization-functionality-be-recreated-using-cereal?noredirect=1#comment100397392_56924828), I was able to alter the `Message` struct to be deserializable without first knowing what it contained:

```
struct A {};

struct B {};

struct Message {
    enum Type {
        A,
        B,
    };

    Type type;

    unique_ptr<::A> a = nullptr;
    unique_ptr<::B> b = nullptr;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& archive) {
        archive(type, contents);
    }
};
```

The trick was to not make the `Message` struct a template.

My first approach at writing the `Message` struct was to included the templeted member variable `contents` for storing each possible inner struct (an `A` or a `B`). This requires you to know what a serialized `Message` structure contains *before* you can deserialize it, because you'd have to first create the specialized `Message` variable to deserialize the data into.

Instead, you can create a `unique_ptr` for each possible inner data struct. This allows you to create a `Message` struct that isn't templated, and you don't have to create a specialized `Message` variable to deserialize the data into.